# Thread function gets only called once. I need it to run in the background

Tags: c++, stdthread

I have a runner task, (something similar to audrino runner). In the Run Function, I have the following code. When I run this code, I find that the `EModule::doRun()` gets only called once.
What I actually want to do is for the thread to keep running in the background, and set the flag in `downloadCompleted`. How do I acheive this? Do I have to make the thread detached ?

```
m_downloadThread = std::thread(&EModule::doRun, this, true,
                [this](bool value) {
                this->setDownloadCompleted(value);
});
if (isDownloadCompleted()) {
    completionFunc(m_downloadSpeed >= m_testThresholdInBps);
}
```

Comment: If you want it to run forever, just encase the contents of the function in your favorite infinite loop. If you don't want `doRun` to have an infinite loop in it, make a wrapper function that calls `doRun` from within an infinite loop, and send that wrapper function to the `std::thread` constructor.

Comment: Infinite loops are the work of Stan. I recommend building in something that allows you to kick out politely on program exit or what-have-you.

Comment: @user4581301 - who is stan ? and can you explain in a bit more detail

Comment: @user4 agreed. What I've done is send a `std::atomic<bool> terminate_flag` as a function parameter, and loop `while (terminate_flag== false)`. Then, when the program is gracefully closed, you set `terminate_flag` to `true` and `join` on all the pending threads.

Comment: @John - my question is when the control comes to the above piece of code, does it create the thread every time? I just want the thread to be created only once. I am passing a bool now, as you can see. I will make it `std::atomic<bool>`

Comment: You keep running `m_downloadThread = std::thread...`? That will keep spawning new threads, yes. If you happen to do this assignment when the previously-assigned thread is still running, `terminate()` will be called on the currently running thread. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D

Comment: @John - Is there a way to assign a thread, and then start the thread.

Comment: @liv I supposed you could create a `std::promise<bool>` and a `std::future<bool>` as described here. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise The worker thread takes the `std::future<bool>` and you do some operation like `bool read = future_object.get()`. Then in the main thread, when you're ready for your worker thread to run you do `promise_object.set_value(true)` (or `false`, doesn't matter, we just set it to anything).